# How do I get a specific (active) class that is running

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-unittest

In this case I want to get the currently active / running unittest that is running using python 2.7.  As you can see by the example code below I don't want curTestEnv to exist.  Nor do I want the setUp() method to exist.  I simply want to dynamically get the current test environment and ask for its test name by calling the id() method for that class.

Is this possible?

```
import unittest

curTestEnv = None       # don't require this

def verify( expected, actual ):
    if( expected != actual ):
        # How do I dynamically get test environment??
        # print 'From TC: ' + unittest.TestCase.id()
        print 'From Env: ' + curTestEnv.id()        # Log TestName
        assert expected == actual, 'Failed: ' + str( curTestEnv.id())

# Reusable Test
def theTest( exp ):
    verify( exp, 'keith2' )

def otherTest( exp ):
    theTest( exp )

class SomeTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp( self ):      
        global curTestEnv       # don't require this
        curTestEnv = self

    def test_one( self ):
        theTest( 'keith' )

    def test_two( self ):
        otherTest( 'keith2')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main( argv=sys.argv, testRunner = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2))
```

This technique would be great to use in a bunch situations.

Comment: You already have `self` in every method—what do you want to do with it?

Comment: The usage is outside of the unittest class.  As stated...I want to find out if there is a method to dynamically get the currently running / active class based on the unittest then use it to call the id() method.  The key here is I don't want to force some 120 to 135 unittest classes to include the curTestEnv initialization.  It would also effect any new class I create.  I just want the lower level code to find the active test class and call id().  More of a Python question then the unittest example given above.

Comment: It’s usually best to send information explicitly rather than ask environmental questions.  But that doesn’t mean you have to type it every time: instead, put the `verify` function in the test class.  For your many different `TestCase` classes, have them derive from an intermediate base class that defines `verify` (and any other “reusable test” methods).

Comment: That again is not feasible or reasonable.  I have almost 200 test suites and I might want multiple functions in lower level code to have access.  While your suggestion will work just like my work around neither are elegant as they would cause unnatural usages of classes and groupings of functions.  I can rethink what you are asking but I believe the loose functions that I want to have access are not ones that I want to put into the same class or derive from 1/2 a dozen other classes.  THANK!!

Comment: Obviously, “reasonable” is a matter of taste—I don’t consider global variables or stack introspection (which seems to be what you actually want) to be more reasonable than designing a test system that knows that it is a test system.

Comment: I prefer to design things a little more generically.  Everything is more reusable instead of using it only for testing.  In this case I'm finding Python limited not providing enough debugging functionality.  Also your last suggestion would add tons of code to each of these 200 test suites.  Duplicating code is not very generic.  I do appreciate your suggestion as each of these experiences allows everybody to learn more about this language we use.

Comment: Not to be adversarial, but I don’t think it counts as more generic to hide a function’s “what test am I?” parameter.  It still has one; its clients just don’t get to set it.

Comment: Hummm... I guess your missing the point.  There are 200 suites and the work to add a function for each suite for each thing I want to do would be  a HUGE amount of work.  I like many other engineers am looking to maintain less code and not to write that much in the first place.  There is an efficiency in my request.  Python seams to be missing this ability.  Also when I talk about more generically  I'm talking about the logging mechanism and others.  If I hook everything into the testing environment those things are no longer generic.  They can then ONLY be used testing.